# Transforming a query response in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I have a table stored in a postgres database as follows

```
offerId  warehouseId  type   quantity
  1          1         A       2
  1          1         B       5
```

after I make a call to database to get the above data ,I need to convert this into a response of type

```
{
   offerId : 1,
   warehouseId : 1,
   types : [{type :'A' ,quantity:2} , {type : 'B' , quantity:5}]
}
```

Is there any way to do this using java spring boot? or any SQL queries which does the same?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I have tried, no luck , But I am very new to backend , So I am struggling a lot

Comment: Checkout jOOQ Multiset https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can add the FOR JSON AUTO at the end of your SQL statement which will produce a JSON string of the results of the SQL so:

```
SELECT offerId, warehouseId, type, quantity FROM your_table FOR JSON AUTO;
```

and in MySQL you can use JSON_OBJECT:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('offerId', offerId, 'warehouseId', warehouseId, 'type', type, 'quantity', quantity) FROM your_table;
```

EDIT:
Create the Types JSON array of objects as follows:

In Java:

```
//Creating a json array
JSONArray Types = new JSONArray();

//Creating a JSONObject object
JSONObject type = new JSONObject();
type.put("type", "A");
type.put("quantity", 1);

Types.add(type);

JSONObject type1 = new JSONObject();
type1.put("type", "B");
type1.put("quantity", 2);

Types.add(type1)
```

In Javascript:

```
function type(type_, quantity) {
  this.type_ = type_;
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }

// create array Types
var Types = [];
// add objects to the array
Types.push(new type("A", 1));
Types.push(new type("B", 2));
```

Comment: I need a response of type mentioned in the question  the types attribute will be an array of objects , each object will have a type attribute and a quantity attribute corresponding to the offerId and nodeId, I believe this wont solve the problem , I appreciate for your answer . Can that be done using java ?

Comment: Ok, cypher. I have extended my answer for the types attribute!